# in reactjs I am trying to have a button let user stay logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to reactjs and I am trying to add a form with a "keep me signed in" checkbox. This my setup so far but I am not getting my desired result. would appreciate any help. thanks

```
       <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={this.state.signInForm.email}
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={this.handleSigninChange} />

        <Input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={this.state.signInForm.password}
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={this.handleSigninChange} />

       <Input
          type="checkbox"
          name="save_login_state"
          label="Keep me signed in"
          checked={false}
          onChange={this.handleLoggedInState.bind(this)} />

        handleLoggedInState: function () {
        this.state.signInForm.email = true;
          },
```

My stay logged in checkbox is not doing anything at this time. it won't even let me check it.

Comment: What aren't you getting? What's the issue?

Comment: Please share this component's class file, as you're using `controlled components`.

Comment: If the issue is with the checked value you'll want to use `defaultChecked` instead of `checked`.

Comment: You have hard-coded `checked` to `false`: `checked={false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you are setting the state variable value is not proper, and use a state variable to maintain the state of checkbox,one more thing you are using `I` in input field instead of that it should be `i` (if you are using the default input elements), try this:

```
handleLoggedInState: function () {
    this.setState({checkboxValue: !this.state.checkboxValue});
},

<input
      type="checkbox"
      name="save_login_state"
      label="Keep me signed in"
      checked={this.state.checkboxValue}
      onChange={this.handleLoggedInState.bind(this)} />
```

Check the `jsFiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xep3mskr/

Answer (score 1):

The issue in you example is that you've hardcoded the checkbox value to `false`. Try this instead:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="save_login_state"
  label="Keep me signed in"
  checked={this.state.saveLoginState}
  onChange={this.toggleLoginState.bind(this)}
/>

  toggleLoginState: function () {
      this.setState({saveLoginState: !this.state.saveLoginState});
  }
```

Also, you should always bind your functions in the constructor.

e.g

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // bind your component functions in the constructor
  this.toggleLoginState = this.toggleLoginState.bind(this);
}
```